# Does the portable ZIP version of Blender have any perfomance differences?

Tags: versions

So I want to use the portable ZIP version of Blender, and as far as I know the functionalities are exactly the same as the install version.

But are there any perfomance differences between the portable ZIP and install versions of Blender?

Answer (score 2):

There are no performance differences between the versions. All official release versions are compiled with the same optimization levels and are functionally identical.

There could be performance difference depending on where the executable is located. If you have multiple HDDs and SSDs, then the loading times may be faster on an SSD. The portable ZIP version gives you the flexibility to place it anywhere you like. Hence, this is even a potential performance benefit.

Comment: i like the zip version which allows me to have several versions like 2.93, 3.0, 3.1

Comment: There's a minor difference between the ZIP (also known as standalone) and the installer version which makes the standalone slightly slower in specific cases.
The one installed via the installer also install the required local system files (dll) required for certain 3D feature in the OS-based cache (which is faster) while the standalone will regenerate those DLL file during the execution and are stored into the RAM. (In short, the installer version is lighter on the RAM and CPU, but it's minor.)